# Silverlight printing with ListBox

Tags: silverlight, printing, listbox

I need to print a complex document with paging from silverlight. Ihave found a good project from http://silverlightreporting.codeplex.com/. Playing with this example, i have found, that more complex templates works not correctly:

I have add a ChildNames property:

```
  public class EmployeeReviewReportItem
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public int PerformanceRating { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public decimal Bonus { get; set; }

        public string ReviewComments { get; set; }

        public string[] ChildNames { set; get; }
}
```

in ReportData.cs set value for this property:

```
ChildNames = new string[] { firstNames.Random(), firstNames.Random(), firstNames.Random() }
```

and then in MainPage.xaml a new ListBox to show this prperty:

```
...
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Text="{Binding ReviewComments}" />

                            <ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNames}">
                             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Width="300"
                                                       Height="auto"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                       Text="{Binding .}"
                                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
...
```

ListBox will be rendered without content.

How i can get Child names printed?

Answer (score 0):

Does `{Binding .}` work? I've never seen it (of course that doesn't mean it isn't correct). I would just use `{Binding}` instead. If that doesn't work then you can try changing `string[]` to `ObservableCollection<string>` and also make the binding a twoway binding: `ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNames, Mode=TwoWay}"`.

Without seeing the complete source code, I can't really help much more than this.